# bitbake st-image-weston -c populate_sdk fails with multiple errors

Tags: qt, arm, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

I am trying to build the yocto projects with the instructions given here:
https://wiki.somlabs.com/index.php/OpenSTLinux_for_VisionSOM-STM32MP1
But when i tried to generate the sdk via command :bitbake st-image-weston -c populate_sdk
it fails with following logs ( a small snapshot of a huge 2k+ fail log):

```
| /home/npal/openstlinux/build-openstlinuxweston-stm32mp157a-visionsom-dsi-sd-mx/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/qtconnectivity/5.14.2+gitAUTOINC+b445ea4ff2-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/arm-ostl-linux-gnueabi/../../libexec/arm-ostl-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-ostl-linux-gnueabi/9.3.0/ld: .obj/qleadvertiser_bluez.o: in function `QLeAdvertiser::~QLeAdvertiser()':
| /usr/src/debug/qtconnectivity/5.14.2+gitAUTOINC+b445ea4ff2-r0/git/src/bluetooth/qleadvertiser_p.h:81: undefined reference to `QLowEnergyAdvertisingData::~QLowEnergyAdvertisingData()'
| /home/npal/openstlinux/build-openstlinuxweston-stm32mp157a-visionsom-dsi-sd-mx/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/qtconnectivity/5.14.2+gitAUTOINC+b445ea4ff2-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/arm-ostl-linux-gnueabi/../../libexec/arm-ostl-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-ostl-linux-gnueabi/9.3.0/ld: /usr/src/debug/qtconnectivity/5.14.2+gitAUTOINC+b445ea4ff2-r0/git/src/bluetooth/qleadvertiser_p.h:81: undefined reference to `QLowEnergyAdvertisingData::~QLowEnergyAdvertisingData()'
| /home/npal/openstlinux/build-openstlinuxweston-stm32mp157a-visionsom-dsi-sd-mx/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/qtconnectivity/5.14.2+gitAUTOINC+b445ea4ff2-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/arm-ostl-linux-gnueabi/../../libexec/arm-ostl-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-ostl-linux-gnueabi/9.3.0/ld: /usr/src/debug/qtconnectivity/5.14.2+gitAUTOINC+b445ea4ff2-r0/git/src/bluetooth/qleadvertiser_p.h:81: undefined reference to `QLowEnergyAdvertisingParameters::~QLowEnergyAdvertisingParameters()'
| /home/npal/openstlinux/build-openstlinuxweston-stm32mp157a-visionsom-dsi-sd-mx/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/qtconnectivity/5.14.2+gitAUTOINC+b445ea4ff2-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/arm-ostl-linux-gnueabi/../../libexec/arm-ostl-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-ostl-linux-gnueabi/9.3.0/ld: .obj/qleadvertiser_bluez.o: in function `QLeAdvertiserBluez::doStartAdvertising()':
| /usr/src/debug/qtconnectivity/5.14.2+gitAUTOINC+b445ea4ff2-r0/git/src/bluetooth/qleadvertiser_bluez.cpp:105: undefined reference to `QLowEnergyAdvertisingData::includePowerLevel() const'
| /home/npal/openstlinux/build-openstlinuxweston-stm32mp157a-visionsom-dsi-sd-mx/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/qtconnectivity/5.14.2+gitAUTOINC+b445ea4ff2-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/arm-ostl-linux-gnueabi/../../libexec/arm-ostl-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-ostl-linux-gnueabi/9.3.0/ld: /usr/src/debug/qtconnectivity/5.14.2+gitAUTOINC+b445ea4ff2-r0/git/src/bluetooth/qleadvertiser_bluez.cpp:106: undefined reference to `QLowEnergyAdvertisingData::includePowerLevel() const'
| /home/npal/openstlinux/build-openstlinuxweston-stm32mp157a-visionsom-dsi-sd-mx/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/qtconnectivity/5.14.2+gitAUTOINC+b445ea4ff2-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/arm-ostl-linux-gnueabi/../../libexec/arm-ostl-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-ostl-linux-gnueabi/9.3.0/ld: .obj/qlowenergycontroller_bluez.o: in function `QLowEnergyControllerPrivateBluez::startAdvertising(QLowEnergyAdvertisingParameters const&, QLowEnergyAdvertisingData const&, QLowEnergyAdvertisingData const&)':
| /usr/src/debug/qtconnectivity/5.14.2+gitAUTOINC+b445ea4ff2-r0/git/src/bluetooth/qlowenergycontroller_bluez.cpp:489: undefined reference to `QLowEnergyAdvertisingParameters::mode() const'
| /home/npal/openstlinux/build-openstlinuxweston-stm32mp157a-visionsom-dsi-sd-mx/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/qtconnectivity/5.14.2+gitAUTOINC+b445ea4ff2-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/arm-ostl-linux-gnueabi/../../libexec/arm-ostl-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-ostl-linux-gnueabi/9.3.0/ld: /usr/src/debug/qtconnectivity/5.14.2+gitAUTOINC+b445ea4ff2-r0/git/src/bluetooth/qlowenergycontroller_bluez.cpp:490: undefined reference to `QLowEnergyAdvertisingParameters::mode() const'
| /home/npal/openstlinux/build-openstlinuxweston-stm32mp157a-visionsom-dsi-sd-mx/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/qtconnectivity/5.14.2+gitAUTOINC+b445ea4ff2-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/arm-ostl-linux-gnueabi/../../libexec/arm-ostl-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-ostl-linux-gnueabi/9.3.0/ld: .obj/qlowenergycontroller_bluez.o: in function `QLowEnergyControllerPrivateBluez::addToGenericAttributeList(QLowEnergyServiceData const&, unsigned short)':
| /usr/src/debug/qtconnectivity/5.14.2+gitAUTOINC+b445ea4ff2-r0/git/src/bluetooth/qlowenergycontroller_bluez.cpp:3340: undefined reference to `QLowEnergyService::serviceUuid() const'
| /home/npal/openstlinux/build-openstlinuxweston-stm32mp157a-visionsom-dsi-sd-mx/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/qtconnectivity/5.14.2+gitAUTOINC+b445ea4ff2-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/arm-ostl-linux-gnueabi/../../libexec/arm-ostl-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-ostl-linux-gnueabi/9.3.0/ld: /usr/src/debug/qtconnectivity/5.14.2+gitAUTOINC+b445ea4ff2-r0/git/src/bluetooth/qlowenergycontroller_bluez.cpp:3346: undefined reference to `QLowEnergyService::serviceUuid() const'
| /home/npal/openstlinux/build-openstlinuxweston-stm32mp157a-visionsom-dsi-sd-mx/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/qtconnectivity/5.14.2+gitAUTOINC+b445ea4ff2-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/arm-ostl-linux-gnueabi/../../libexec/arm-ostl-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-ostl-linux-gnueabi/9.3.0/ld: .obj/moc_qlowenergyservice.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x20): undefined reference to `QLowEnergyService::~QLowEnergyService()'
| /home/npal/openstlinux/build-openstlinuxweston-stm32mp157a-visionsom-dsi-sd-mx/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/qtconnectivity/5.14.2+gitAUTOINC+b445ea4ff2-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/arm-ostl-linux-gnueabi/../../libexec/arm-ostl-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-ostl-linux-gnueabi/9.3.0/ld: .obj/moc_qlowenergyservice.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x24): undefined reference to `QLowEnergyService::~QLowEnergyService()'
| collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
| make[2]: *** [Makefile:428: ../../lib/libQt5Bluetooth.so.5.14.2] Error 1
| make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/npal/openstlinux/build-openstlinuxweston-stm32mp157a-visionsom-dsi-sd-mx/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/qtconnectivity/5.14.2+gitAUTOINC+b445ea4ff2-r0/build/src/bluetooth'
| make[1]: *** [Makefile:50: sub-bluetooth-make_first] Error 2
| make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/npal/openstlinux/build-openstlinuxweston-stm32mp157a-visionsom-dsi-sd-mx/tmp-glibc/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi/qtconnectivity/5.14.2+gitAUTOINC+b445ea4ff2-r0/build/src'
| make: *** [Makefile:49: sub-src-make_first] Error 2
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| 
NOTE: recipe qtconnectivity-5.14.2+gitAUTOINC+b445ea4ff2-r0: task do_compile: Failed
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 4091 tasks of which 4083 didn't need to be rerun and 4 failed.
NOTE: Writing buildhistory
NOTE: Writing buildhistory took: 2 seconds

Summary: 4 tasks failed:
  /home/npal/openstlinux/layers/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qtserialbus_git.bb:do_compile
  /home/npal/openstlinux/layers/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qttools_git.bb:do_compile
  /home/npal/openstlinux/layers/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qtcharts_git.bb:do_compile
  /home/npal/openstlinux/layers/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qtconnectivity_git.bb:do_compile
Summary: There were 8 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

Any leads how to get past this ?? I am struggling to find any solution.
An earliest response will be really helpful.